# syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, codeigniter

aún ando nuevo en el tema de PHP y estoy intentando hacer un login con codeigniter, pues al momento de llamar al modelo(Auth_model) desde el controlador(Auth) me salta un error:

** syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)00**

*Auth_model.php*

```
<?php
class Auth_model extends CI_Model {
public class __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}

public function getUser($email)
{
$this->db->where('user_email', $email);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
return $query->row();
}

 }
```

*Auth.php*

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Auth_model');
}

public function login(){
$data = new stdClass();
$data->title = "Proyecto CI";
$data->contenido = "auth/login";
$data->panel_title = "Inicio de Sesión";
$data->active = "login";
$this->load->view('frontend', $data);
}

public function signin(){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'Email',                                                       'required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[16]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->login();
  }
else
  {
    $correo = $this->input->post('correo');
    $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
    $user = $this->Auth_model->getUser($correo);
    print_r($user);
    exit;
  }
}
}
```

Pues ya vi todos los puntos y comas y sigue sin funcionar, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Esto esta mal: `public class __construct(){` debería ser `public function __construct(){`

Comment: Cierto, muchas gracias